# Eliminate buffering of a child process data

Tags: node.js, parent-child, child-process

I try to create a child process from node.js script (parent) in the way where will be no interference between the parent and child data flow. The parent should only have the child process id when a child process start and be able to terminate it. `child_process.exec` does part of what I need but unfortunately it buffers child's output and therefore as the buffer gets full the child crashes. Is there a way to eliminate the buffering? The child process is infinite in its nature (data stream). Or may be there is other way to implement the controls?

Code sample (just for demo):

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const keypress = require('keypress');
keypress(process.stdin);

var c1;

process.stdin.on('keypress', (letter, key) => {
    if (key && key.name == 'a') {
        c1.kill();
    } else if (key && key.name == 'b') {
        c1 = exec('ffplay -i udp://localhost:4000', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`error: ${err}`);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried `spawn` but there child - parent interference is even more severe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `child_process.spawn` instead, you should be able to call it with options for `stdio`:

```
spawn(cmd, [], { stdio: 'ignore' });
```

[child_process.spawn docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

EDIT:

If you are a fan of `Promise`, here's a util fn I wrote to help with things

```
const quietSpawn = (cmd, args = []) => {
    const splitCmd = cmd.split(' ');

    if (splitCmd.length > 1) {
        [cmd, ...args] = splitCmd;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const proc = spawn(cmd, args, { stdio: 'ignore' });

        proc.on('exit', resolve);
        proc.on('error', reject);
    });
};
```

Comment: it should be `spawn` not `exec` at the top